# Plot ROC or PR curves from either the X,Y coordinates (i.e TPR/TNR; or PPV/TPR) or list of predictions (class probabilities)?

Tags: data-visualization, cross-validation, svm, roc, precision-recall

I have a list of X,Y coordinates for plotting both a ROC curve and a PR curve.  I also have the data which was used to calculate those coordinates (i.e. a list of individual predictions with binary class probabilities made from the test sets from an outer-cross-validation procedure).

Which software or package can I use to plot the curves using this data as the input? I know that I could use a scatter plot in Excel, but it would lack the features (e.g. highlighting the harmonic/geometric mean; etc) and the general look and feel of a ROC curve or PR curve, so I would rather use a pre-existing specialist package for the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work in R, have a look at [ROCR](https://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about a specific software package for this purpose but I can recommend either Matplotlib for python or Matlab/Octave.